# Rails Ajax requests not showing up on other computers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building an app where a user can post something, and the post will appear on the index page using Ajax so no need to refresh, it works fine for the user posting the post, but other users browsing the website still need to refresh to see the new post.

Here is the controller :

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('id DESC')
    @post = Post.new
end
```

d

```
ef create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: "Study request successfully added" }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    end
end
```

And here is the javascript

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>").prependTo("#container");
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have a look at gems such as `faye-rails`, `firehose`, or `private_pub`. Or services like `pusher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to implement long polling into your page or use web sockets.

Other browsers don't get magically updated because those pages have already been loaded and won't get any further requests. (there is a difference between the server, serving the page and the browsers loading those pages).

If you implement long polling or web sockets into your page, you're requiring the browser to continuously listen to changes or incoming data from your server.

in doing so, [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), [(github version of faye)](https://github.com/faye/faye) seemed to do the trick for me in the past. (which requires you to setup another server besides your rails app, which will listen to change calls from your rails app and push those to the listening clients) (it also integrates long polling if you wish).

Also you could poll for changes yourself periodically with java script (a simple `setTimeout`, set to every second or so would give the approximately the same result).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the path, will accept once I can. Any gems that make polling or web sockets easier?